# PHP case switch with or condition

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to use SWITCH CASE condition with 'or' for get one or other value received from form. But always getting into first condition 'here! 1'. Someone can help me to identify the error into the code?
I already try using [('value1' || 'value2')] and ['value1' || 'value'] the the both doesnt work because always returnin "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs - here! 1"

```
<?php
$sDDDA = $_POST['DDDA'];
$sNumA = $_POST['NumA'];
$sDtInit = $_POST['DtInit'];
$sDtEnd = $_POST['DtEnd'];
$sIdProduct = $_POST['IdProduct'];
$sAnoMes = $_POST['AnoMes'];
$sDDDs = $_POST['DDDs'];
$sMSISDN = $_POST['DDDA'] . $_POST['NumA'];
$s55MSISDN = "55" . $_POST['DDDA'] . $_POST['NumA'];

echo "The value of the variable DDDA is: $sDDDA <br>";
echo "The value of the variable NumA is: $sNumA <br>";
echo "The value of the variable DtInit is: $sDtInit <br>";
echo "The value of the variable DtEnd is: $sDtEnd <br>";
echo "The value of the variable AnoMes is: $sAnoMes <br>";
echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs <br>";
echo "The value of the variable MSISDN is: $sMSISDN <br>";
echo "The value of the variable 55MSISDN is: $s55MSISDN <br>";
echo "</b><br><br>";

switch($_POST['IdProduct']){
case 'Conecta':

echo "The value of the variable IdProduct is: $sIdProduct - here! <b>1</b><br><br>";

    switch ($_POST['AnoMes']){
    case ('ate_201803'||'201804_201902'):
    echo "The value of the variable AnoMes is: $sAnoMes - here! <b>1</b><br><br>";

        switch ($_POST['DDDs']){
        case '1x4x5x6x':
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs - here! <b>1 - 1x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        case '2x3x7x8x9x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs - here! <b>1 - 2x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        default:
        echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable DDD! here! <b>1</b><br><br>';
          
        }

    break;
    case 'apartir_201903':
    echo "The value of the variable AnoMes is: $sAnoMes - here! <b>5</b><br><br>";

        switch ($_POST['DDDs']){
        case '1x4x5x6x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs  - here! <b>5 - 1x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        case '2x3x7x8x9x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs  - here! <b>5 - 2x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        default:
        echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable DDD! here! <b>5</b><br><br>';
          
        }

    break;
    default:
    echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable AnoMes!</b><br><br>';
    }

break;
case 'Recado':

echo "The value of the variable IdProduct is: $sIdProduct - here! <b>3<br>";

    switch ($_POST['AnoMes']){
    case ('ate_201803'||'201804_201902'):
    echo "The value of the variable AnoMes is: $sAnoMes - here! <b>3<br>";

        switch ($_POST['DDDs']){
        case '1x4x5x6x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs - here! <b>3 - 1x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        case '2x3x7x8x9x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs - here! <b>3 - 2x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        default:
        echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable DDD! here! <b>3</b><br><br>';
          
        }

    break;
    case 'apartir_201903':
    echo "The value of the variable AnoMes is: $sAnoMes - here! <b>4<br>";

        switch ($_POST['DDDs']){
        case '1x4x5x6x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs  - here! <b>4 - 1x </b><br><br>";
    
        break;
        case '2x3x7x8x9x' :
        echo "The value of the variable DDDs is: $sDDDs  - here! <b>4 - 2x </b><br><br>";

        break;
        default:
        echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable DDD! here! <b>4</b><br><br>';
          
        }

    break;
    default:
    echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable AnoMes!</b><br><br>';

    }

break;
default:
echo 'ERRO! The value is wrong for variable AnoMes!</b><br><br>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Also I'm already tried change 'switch ($_POST['AnoMes'])' to 'switch ($sAnoMes)' abd result is the same.

Comment: You can't use an OR in a case statement. Just add 2 cases without a break between the two. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: all right, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ur `case`s are evalutating to bools if you use logical operators.

so when you have `case ('ate_201803'||'201804_201902')` PHP sees `case true`.

To use the equivalent of `OR` just list the cases below each other:

```
switch ($value) {
  case 'ate_201803':
  case '201804_201902':
    // ...
  break;
}
```